# Erlang io:format Buffering and Efficiency

Tags: file-io, erlang, performance

This question is specific to Erlang, but may have general implications to other IO libraries. In Erlang, I can write `io:format(IOF, "data: ~p", [Data])` and it will print the contents of the variable `Data` to the file `IOF` points to. My question is this: is it better, efficiency-wise, to prefer many small io:format() calls, or one huge one? For example, what would be faster? For purposes of demonstration, assume the size of my `Data` variables is `1KB` each in size, and `N > 100,000`

Scenario A:

```
io:format(IOF, "data1: ~p", [Data1])
io:format(IOF, "data2: ~p", [Data2])
...
io:format(IOF, "dataN: ~p", [DataN])
```

Scenario B:

```
io:format(IOF, "data1: ~p data2: ~p ... dataN: ~p", [Data1, Data2, ..., DataN])
```

If this difference is negligible I'm not really interested, but if there could be a large difference then I'm interested in knowing why.

Comment: io & io_lib is the slowest shit ever. Consider using logging libraries or fast operation on raw files.

Comment: Why is it slow, and why would using a 3rd part logging library be faster?

Comment: I am not familiar with internal implementation. IO was always a performance problem in Erlang and believe me io and io_lib will impact your system. Use fprof (profiler) to see how high are those funcions.

Comment: Use `timer:tc/1` or `timer:tc/3` to measure when in doubt. It is way easier to check something directly than guessing at what is fastest.

Comment: As for the actual calls, calling `io:format(..., [D1, D2, D3])` will be faster because of less new function calls being made. If it makes a difference really depends on how often you're calling the function. Again, measure to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to research on [`file:open/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2) modes, one of which is `{delayed_write, Size, Delay}`. It allows you to buffer data and effectively write it to the device.

This way either calls wouldn't probably make a huge difference.

Comment: So delay_write will let me specify how many bytes to load into the buffer before its dumped, regardless of how many io:format calls are made?